# AVPlayer Statement for buffering

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am using the AVPlayer to play a live stream from the Internet, and need to show than the player is buffering :

I am using an NStimer :

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(buffering) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)buffering {

if(radiosound.rate == 1.0)
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

else 
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

 }
```

For sure rate property is not working properly to show !
Is it an other statement to know if the AVPlayer is buffering ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at setting up key-value observers for the loaded times, and use that to figure out if you are waiting for data at the current play point.

Observers are setup using `addObserver:self forKeyPath: options: context:` method on `AVPlayerItem` and then in the `observeValueForKeyPath: ofObject: change: context:` callback you can figure out what times have been loaded compared with where in the item the player is playing.

You won't see the `rate` variable drop to zero when buffering, as this is the *desired* playback rate, not the actual rate being achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSURLConnection class in conjunction with the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol.